# Almacenar esta Expresión a una Pila

Tags: c++, pilas

Estoy tratando de enviar esta expresión a una pila y luego imprimir los elementos de la pila.

¿Por qué solo se está almacenando el primer carácter de toda la expresión, o el problema será al imprimir los datos de la pila?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows>

#define Tamanio 20

struct PilaDato{
    PilaDato *Sig;
   char Info;
};

PilaDato *Pil=NULL;

PilaDato *Insertar(PilaDato *&,char);
PilaDato *Muestra(PilaDato *);

int op,Tope=-1,Pos=-1,Pila[Tamanio],Epos[Tamanio],Tamexp;
char Exp[Tamanio],Sim,E,j=0;
int Pri(char Sim);

void main(){
    printf("\nINGRESE UNA EXPRESION: ");
   scanf("%s",&Exp);
   Tope=-1;
   Pos=-1;
   Tamexp=strlen(Exp);
   for(int i=0;i<Tamexp;i++){
        Sim=Exp[i];
      if(Sim=='('){
        Tope=Tope+1;
         Pila[Tope]=Sim;
      }else if(Sim==')'){
        while(Pila[Tope]!='('){
            Pos=Pos+1;
            Epos[Pos]=Pila[Tope];
            Tope=Tope-1;
         }
         Tope=Tope-1;
      }else if((Sim>='0')){
        Pos=Pos+1;
         Epos[Pos]=Sim;
      }else if((Sim=='.')){
        Pos=Pos+1;
         Epos[Pos]=Sim;
      }else{
        while(Tope>-1 && (Pri(Sim)<=Pri(Pila[Tope]))){
            Pos=Pos+1;
            Epos[Pos]=Pila[Tope];
            Tope=Tope-1;
         }
         Tope=Tope+1;
         Pila[Tope]=Sim;
      }
   }
   while(Tope>=-1){
    Pos=Pos+1;
      Epos[Pos]=Pila[Tope];
      Tope=Tope-1;
   }

   printf("\nLA EXPRESION POSTFIJA ES: ");
   for(int i=0;i<=Pos;i++){
    printf("%c",Epos[i]);
   }
   E=Epos[j];
   Insertar(Pil,E);
   printf("\nLA EXPRESION EN LA PILA ES: ");
   Muestra(Pil);
    cout<<endl;
    system("pause");
}

int Pri(char Sim){
    int Ret;
    switch(Sim){
    case '^': Ret=3; break;
      case '/': Ret=2; break;
      case '*': Ret=2; break;
      case '-': Ret=1; break;
      case '+': Ret=1; break;
      case ')': Ret=0; break;
      case '(': Ret=0; break;
   }
   return Ret;
}

PilaDato *Insertar(PilaDato *&Pil,char E){
   E=Epos[j];
    if(Pil==NULL){
    Pil=(PilaDato *)malloc(sizeof(PilaDato));
      Pil->Info=E;
      Pil->Sig=NULL;
      return Pil;
   }else{
    if(j<=Pos){
        Insertar(Pil->Sig,E);
         j++;
      }
   }
}

PilaDato *Muestra(PilaDato *Pil){
    if(Pil==NULL){
    return NULL;
   }else{
    cout<<Pil->Info<<endl;
      Muestra(Pil->Sig);
   }
}
```

Comment: Si realmente estás en C++, considera usar lo que te brinda STL. `iostream`, `string`, `vector`, `stack`, `new`, `delete`, etc.

Comment: Por otro lado, fíjate que solo añades un elemento a la pila. Solo haces una llamada `Insertar(Pil, E)` y esta llamada está fuera de los bucles, luego, por lógica, solo va a haber un elemento en la pila

Comment: Has mostrado la salida incorrecta, pero no has mostrado cuál es la salida que esperabas ¿podrías añadirlo, por favor?